# Jelly Bean (4.1.2) Support for Proxy Auto-Configuration PAC Files?

Tags: proxy

I'm managing Samsung Galaxy Note I & IIs running Android 4.1.2 and would like to direct network/browser traffic to a URL filtering service through a proxy server. Can someone confirm (with supporting reference material please) or deny (with supporting reference material please) that Jelly Bean (specifically Android v4.1.2) has support for PAC files to configure proxy settings? I've had more then one person state Jelly Bean has "basic PAC support" yet I can't find anything on the subject.  The goal would be to autodeploy a PAC file onto the devices.

The browsers I want to redirect to the proxy are Internet V4.1.2 (default with version 4.1.2) and Chrome V 25.0.1364.169. Do either or both of these support URL definition of a server based PAC file?  ie. Can they use a URL pointer to the PAC config?

If PAC file support does exist where does the PAC file need to be installed? How is it typically installed? Can someone point me to documentation that reviews the PAC file support.

Thanks for the time and consideration.  Its appreciated.